# Flask TemplateNotFound

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am new to flask and try to run a very simple python file which calls an HTML document, but whenever I search on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`, it raises the TemplateNotFound error. I searched stack overflow on similar questions, but even with implementing the solutions, I get the same error. Nothing worked so far

**base.html contains:**

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello there</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**flask_test_2.py contains:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('base.html')
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

as advised in some of the solutions, I checked the file structure:

```
/flask_test_2.py
/templates
    /base.html
```

Comment: Have you configured the environment? Once you have your env on you must run flask from there. Example: "cd c:\projects\myproject" than prompt "flask run" . So you will see a message saying your server is ready and running in http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: Your example works perfectly for me.

Comment: Your application works fine for me. Except for a possible typo, there is no indication why the code shouldn't run.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Since is doesn't, you may take out the
`template_folder='templates' portion of you` app` assignment and have it this way:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('base.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

it will use the `templates` directory by default.

The issue you are experiencing may be path related. You may also declare the app variable this way:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='usr\...\templates')
```

Comment: I added ```template_folder``` as one of the solutions since it didn't work without it either, but I will try adding the entire path, thank you

Comment: I think I have tried everything now, still nothing... thank you nonetheless